# How to use cx_freeze with pyautoit?

Tags: python, windows, autoit, cx-freeze

I want to create a cx_freeze executable from my windows application that use "pyautoit" module.

```
pip install -U pyautoit
```

This is my example code:

**main.py**

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.win_close("[CLASS:Notepad]")
autoit.control_click("[Class:#32770]", "Button2")
```

**setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["autoit"],
    "excludes": []
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "AutoItSample",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Automate Notepad Editor",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)],
)
```

And I created the build with this command inside my project folder.

```
python setup.py build
```

This module use a .dll file included inside the module folder.

```
autoit
    lib
        AutoItX3.dll
    autoit.py
    ...
```

But cx_freeze doesn't include this .dll in the library.zip archive.
I tried to include the lib folder manually inside the library.zip archive.
But I've got the same error.

http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1428496271.png

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the zip_includes option in your setup.py file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["autoit"],
    "excludes": [],
    "zip_includes": ['AutoITX3.dll']
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "AutoItSample",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Automate Notepad Editor",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)],
)
```